# Javascript slideshow which changes the text 0.5 seconds after the image is changed

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow

I need to make an HTML page with a slideshow. The photos from the slideshow have to change every 2 seconds. And 0.5 seconds after the current image is displayed a text should be displayed over the image. And this should be made without using jQuery or other libraries, just javascript functions. This is what i have right now but its not working properly.

```
var imageIndex = 0;
    var textIndex = 0;
    displayImage();
    displayText();

    function displayImage() {
        var i;
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].style.display = "none";  
        }
        imageIndex++;
        if (imageIndex > x.length) {imageIndex = 1}    
        x[imageIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
        setTimeout(displayImage, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
    }

    function displayText() {
        var i;
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("text");
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].style.display = "none";  
        }
        textIndex++;
        if (textIndex > x.length) {textIndex = 1}    
        x[textIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
        setTimeout(displayText, 2500);          
    }



<div class="container">
    <div class="mySlides">
        <img src="Images/slide1.jpg">
        <div class="text">Yunnan, China</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
        <img src="Images/slide2.jpg">
        <div class="text">Namib Desert, Africa</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
        <img src="Images/slide3.jpg">
        <div class="text">Rapeseed fields in Luoping, China</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
        <img src="Images/slide4.jpg">
        <div class="text">Colorado, USA</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Define "not working properly". Do you get an error? If so, what line is it on? Help us help you. Also, post the relevant HTML so that we can run the code as you have it.

Comment: Your problem is the steps are not correct. 2000-2500, 4000-5000, 6000-7500..... Looking at the times, you see after each iteration, the times keep increasing... Either you need to delay the text by 500 before setting the iteration to 2000 or you just need to trigger the timeout after you change the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're calling displayText every 2500 seconds, which will make your text show en extra 500ms exponentially larger every time

for example,

```
img 1 = 2000
text 1 = 2500 (+500)

img 2 = 4000
text 2 = 5000 (+1000)

img 3 = 6000
text 3 = 7500 (+1500)
```

etc.

you will need to call your displayText() function 500ms after your image fades in.

```
function displayImage() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    imageIndex++;
    if (imageIndex > x.length) {imageIndex = 1}    
    x[imageIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    setTimeout(displayText, 500);
    setTimeout(displayImage, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}

function displayText() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("text");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    textIndex++;
    if (textIndex > x.length) {textIndex = 1}    
    x[textIndex-1].style.display = "block";         
}
```

This should run your function every time an image changes, but only after half a second.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because the display image and display text fire at different times? this should help:

```
    var imageIndex = 0;
    var textIndex = 0;
    var timeText = 0;
    setInterval(displayImage, 2000);

    function displayImage() {
        if(timeText !== 0) { //just in case displayImage() takes more than 2000 miliseconds.
            clearTimeout(timeText);
        }
        var i;
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].style.display = "none";  
        }
        imageIndex++;
        if (imageIndex > x.length) {imageIndex = 1}    
        x[imageIndex-1].style.display = "block";            
        timeText = setTimeout(displayText, 500);
    }

    function displayText() {
        var i;
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("text");
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].style.display = "none";  
        }
        textIndex++;
        if (textIndex > x.length) {textIndex = 1}    
        x[textIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    }
```

Comment: It was just a matter of chaining the events, I'm glad it work... if it's the right answer, please mark it ;) thanks.